# Position an iframe's div relatively to the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, notifyjs

I'm using http://notifyjs.com and I think it's working great.

However I have this issue when applying it to my case.

I want to display a notification using notify.js in the bottom right corner. And this notification should not disappear until users click on it (just to make sure they don't miss it)

When I run my web locally, everything is working fine. The notification is displayed in bottom right corner **of the window**, and it stays there regardless of scrolling.

```
$.notify('HelloWorld',
    {
        className: 'success',
        autoHide: false,
        clickToHide: true,
        position: "bottom right"
    }
);
```

However, when I deploy it to the UAT server in which our web application is only an iframe, the notification is displayed in the corner, but it's in the corner **of the iframe**, so it might go off the users' screen when they scroll, or they can't see it because it appears when they are not the bottom of iframe.

Please help to advise how I can position an iframe's div relatively to the window is possible. Thanks very much in advance.

==================================================

The html looks something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            ...
            <div id="main-content">
                <div id="iframe-container">
                    <iframe id="Main" name="Main" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
                        <html>
                            <body>
                                ...
                                <div class="notifyis-corner" style="right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">...</div>
                            </body>
                        </html>
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can see the css for notifyjs-corner as below:

```
.notifyjs-corner {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 5px;
    z-index: 1050;
}
```

Comment: You can not move your div outside you iframe. Ideally you have to implement the JS function on the top frame.  There is other hacky ways that you can still do it within your iframe, but still, you have to be able to inject at least something, i.e. JS or CSS to the top frame page.

Comment: That's sad to hear, because the outer frame is managed by some other teams. I don't think they would like to change their code just to accommodate my simple small notification :(

Comment: So what space does your iframe occupy? In the center of the page? Will the other team be happy to place your iframe at the right bottom of their page as "position: fixed"?

Comment: My iframe is placed in the middle of the outer page. I still want my iframe in the center. I want only the notifyjs-center to be placed in the corner of the window (although it's inside my iframe). I guess that cannot be done in a clean way?

Comment: sorry man, only the middle of the outer page is your asset, you do not have control beyond that area.

Comment: got it, will try to find some other way to communicate this to the users :)